# Your Google Account is missing a delivery address. You can add an address, then come back and try again

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I use code from actions-on-google apiai-transactions-nodejs but How can I get the Address?

Comment: As noted, it isn't clear what you're trying to, or what you have done and are having problems with. If you can update your question to include code that you've tried, what you've done, and error messages when you've done them, we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the google product page [Google Express] `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ci8sJ1msoNs` the transaction example is created. So, unless you are in USA and develop with the google account, you cannot configure a delivery address.

Looks like we need to wait a little longer in other part of the world.